# Caching WCF Service based on output

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, caching, outputcache

I have this service:

```
public  bool Inquiry( string Plaque)
{

}
```

As you can see the output of my service is `true` or `false` for a specific plaque. I want to cache the output that is `true` for 15 days. I mean, when the result was true for specific plaque, I need to cache this data,so if again the system call my service for that plaque, it should be returned by cache system. Is it possible?

Best regards.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Explore the caching solutions which you can use such as Memcached,

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you ,is it possible to cache some data based on output ?

Comment: You want to store data based on plaque. Plaque is input in your case do i am not sure what you are asking. Caching can be done based on the value. It doesn't matter input or output. You just need to write logic to check the cache before getting value from the database

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No i want to cache the data based on output .I want to store data in cache if the output is 'true' for 15 days

Comment: You mean to say for any value of `plaque` you will have true value?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes sometimes

Comment: `sometimes` That means most of the time different `plaque` will have different output. In that case the logic should be, first you check in the cache if Key <<Plaque>> existing in the cache, if it is there then return it from there, else get the value from what ever datastore you are using and if the value is true then store it in cache with key <<plaque>> and value "True". So next time when the request for same Plaque comes the value will be returned from cache if it is there. While storing in the cache, you can specify the expiration duration also.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes exactly .so could you please give me some reference based on this topology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (_inquiryview.ValidTest == "1")
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpCachePolicy cachePolicy = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache;
            cachePolicy.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate);
            cachePolicy.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(15));
            cachePolicy.VaryByHeaders["Accept"] = true;
            cachePolicy.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Charset"] = true;
            cachePolicy.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
            cachePolicy.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
            cachePolicy.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
        }
```